# join query in Apache solr : how to get all levels in hierarchical data

Tags: join, solr, ancestor

I have a Solr4 index representing child->parent relations between contents with the following relevant fields:

- item_id
- im_endpoints_source_node$nid
- im_endpoints_target_node$nid

Where **item_id** is the relation id, **im_endpoints_source_node$nid** is a multivalue field for the parent document id, and **im_endpoints_target_node$nid** is a multivalue field for the child document id.

Each document may have several children and several parents.

I would like to select all ancestor or descendant relations of a specific document.

Lets assume I have a structure as so:

```
1 > 30
1 > 11
11 > 121
11 > 126
126 > 134
```

I am able to get all direct parent relations with the following select query:

```
/select?fq=im_endpoints_source_node$nid:1
```

Which gives the following results:

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "child_relation_index-9",
        "index_id": "child_relation_index",
        "item_id": "9",
        "is_rid": 9,
        "bs_field_relation_inactive": false,
        "ss_search_api_language": "und",
        "im_endpoints_source_node$nid": [
          1
        ],
        "im_endpoints_target_node$nid": [
          30
        ],
        "timestamp": "2013-09-24T13:03:44.739Z"
      },
      {
        "id": "child_relation_index-13",
        "index_id": "child_relation_index",
        "item_id": "13",
        "is_rid": 13,
        "bs_field_relation_inactive": false,
        "ss_search_api_language": "und",
        "im_endpoints_source_node$nid": [
          1
        ],
        "im_endpoints_target_node$nid": [
          11
        ],
        "timestamp": "2013-09-24T13:03:44.739Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And the 2nd level of ancestor relations (the grandparent relations) with the following select query:

```
/select?fq={!join from=im_endpoints_target_node$nid to=im_endpoints_source_node$nid}im_endpoints_source_node$nid:1
```

Which gives the following results:

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "child_relation_index-18",
        "index_id": "child_relation_index",
        "item_id": "18",
        "is_rid": 18,
        "bs_field_relation_inactive": false,
        "ss_search_api_language": "und",
        "im_endpoints_source_node$nid": [
          11
        ],
        "im_endpoints_target_node$nid": [
          121
        ],
        "timestamp": "2013-09-24T13:03:44.739Z"
      },
      {
        "id": "child_relation_index-19",
        "index_id": "child_relation_index",
        "item_id": "19",
        "is_rid": 19,
        "bs_field_relation_inactive": false,
        "ss_search_api_language": "und",
        "im_endpoints_source_node$nid": [
          11
        ],
        "im_endpoints_target_node$nid": [
          126
        ],
        "timestamp": "2013-09-24T13:03:44.739Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Is there a way to get all ancestors of a document (from level 1 to level N) in one single query ?**

FYI: this index is created using Drupal's Search API Solr module in combination with the Relation module. It contains over 300k relations for about 500k documents.

Any help would be highly appreciated.